# Expected ':' Lexical or Preprocessor error

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

Well this should be a pretty quick and easy question. I am creating a scrollview and i have it all done, but there is an error that i just dont understand it! like its just confusing and  doesnt make sense to me!

THE ERROR:  // Expected ':'

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *ScrollView;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self ScrollView setScrollEnabled YES]    // Expected ':'
[self ScrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(320, 900)]
}
```

EDIT:
I did all of this and it just says expected identifier.

```
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.ScrollView setScrollEnabled: YES];
[[self.ScrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(320, 900)]];    //expected identifier
```

Comment: Please, name your variables with a lower case.

Comment: you've got an extra pair of brackets around that selector.

Comment: I strongly suggest you read up on basic Objective-C syntax before you start polluting stack overflow with questions like this.

Comment: @atreat Im a 16 year old high school kid trying to create a part of an app for school. lay off..

Comment: @BettByteSquad good on you for getting started early. Its a tough world out there.

Comment: And not learning the syntax of the language is going to get you where exactly? It's not like @atreat is being very harsh on you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a colon, a couple of dots, and a couple of semicolons:

```
[self.ScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
//   ^                           ^    ^
[self.ScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 900)];
//   ^                                                ^
```

You need to watch out for these small elements of the syntax - Objective C does not tolerate deviations. The worst part about syntax errors is that you often get a report pointing to a wrong line.

Comment: Ive tried both of those things. When i do that my xcode says that same error on the second line as well as the first one when i do that.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few problems with that line.

```
[self.ScrollView setScrollEnabled: YES];
     ^                           ^     ^
     ^
//I've assumed this was supposed to be either self.ScrollView or _ScrollView
//I can't tell if you are using a custom getter.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[self.ScrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(320, 900)]];
^                                                      ^
|                                                      |
```

Remove these two.