# Expected Identifier or '(' error

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, uiscrollview

i am a High school student. Im completely new too coding and i have a short class that i have chosen to try and create an app for my school. I have succeeded with most of my coding, but i have had the continuous error of, expected identifier or '('. Ive searched all over the internet and I have not found a way to clear the error.

So, i have done two seperate codes and am trying to copy and paste them together right now. and The same error shows up.

Error: expected identifier or '('

```
@interface ViewController()
<UIWebViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
webView.delegate = self;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://twitter.com/u_bett"];
NSURLRequest *urlrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:urlrequest];

}
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request            navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
 if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
{
    return NO;
}

return YES;
}
{               //exected identifier or '('
[self.ScrollView setScrollEnabled: YES];
[self.ScrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(320, 900)];
}




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)Twitter:(id)sender {NSURL *myURL = [NSURL         URLWithString:@"https://twitter.com/u_bett"];
NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];

[webView loadRequest:myRequest];
}

- (IBAction)Facebook:(id)sender {
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/BettSchools"];
NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];

[webView loadRequest:myRequest]; }
```

Edit:
I did as you said and it gave me a couple of errors on the BOOL part of the code. Showed below. 
    }

```
  - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request       navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType    

//Expected ';' after expression

//use of undeclared identifier 'request'
 {
if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
{
    return NO;
}

return YES;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode -- this is a compiler error.

Comment: Also, indent your code. It's an unreadable mess.

Comment: Ctrl-I on a block of code to indent.

Comment: @H2CO3 You are so irascible every day I see your posts. Why does the Xcode thing bother you so much?

Comment: @woz Because it's a horrible misconception. I've been writing Objective-C code without Xcode for 3 years. (And this is *especially* disturbing because people who can't differentiate between the IDE and the compiler are typically the ones who also have absolutely no idea what they are even doing with them, and consequently they post low-quality, duplicated, trivial questions, such as this one, which completely lack research and effort.)

Comment: @H2CO3 whilst I do agree with you - I have noticed you can be a little harsh about it sometimes a simple explanation to the user of why it shouldn't be used would benefit everyone. The person asking the question because they will understand why they shouldn't use it as well as learn something and it will benefit you as you will not have to edit or complain about it. Do you not think?

Comment: As i said in my post. i am a High school student. i have 45 days to completely learn code and create an app. im doing my best...

Comment: @Popeye I do and when I have the patience for that, I usually link the tag wiki for the `xcode` tag (which explains this very well and also says that "this tag should only be used for questions related to the IDE itself"). However, honestly, I've fed up with this. Quite a bit. I don't understand either why would it be necessary for others to provide this information to OP. I haven't asked questions like this on Stack Overflow. I managed to learn to use my programming tools by reading their manual. I managed to figure out the difference between an IDE and a compiler by googling for tutorials. %

Comment: @Popeye So I feel it unwarranted to require *us* (you, me and other SO users, whomsoever encounters such a question) to teach OP these things. (Maybe he should have paid attention in class instead?)

Comment: @user3091822 Guess what - I was a high school student until last year, me too. This doesn't depend on one's degree or age. It's all about effort.

Comment: @H2CO3 I don't think it bothers me as much as it does you so I will normally give an explanation but if it annoys you that much I can understand your comments. People should learn or at least read the tag wiki before reading. But then again we have all been there starting out I would expect it from some as new as the OP but from someone with the rep of like myself it should be expect they know how to tag correctly so I can see both sides of this discussion. Ever way I still agree with you overall.

Comment: How have you "succeeded with most of your coding" when you cannot even get it to compile, much less test it?

Comment: Did you create a new account? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500329/expected-lexical-or-preprocessor-error#comment30643954_20500329

Comment: @H2CO3 I only said anything about xcode because that is the only resource i have for creating the app. Im sorry i may not be as smart as you in this field. But you dont have to completely be a jerk about the entire thing. I have been putting effort towards this.

Comment: @tripleee Because i have been able to test it. This error is new to my project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have block of code that is outside of any functions:

```
{               //exected identifier or '('
[self.ScrollView setScrollEnabled: YES];
[self.ScrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(320, 900)];
}
```

You probably have deleted method definition by accident

Comment: please check my edit. new errors appeared

Comment: @user3091822 You should ask a new question for a new problem, but I think you could work this out on your own. The errors tell you what the compiler is expecting.